# Does ie10 support image pasting from clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, onpaste

Does ie10 support the ability to support copy and pasting an image. IE has the fileReader api which is nice, but it would be cool to have ability to paste a picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good indicator that pasting images into IE10 is not possible, is the nice site http://pasteboard.co. The site tries really hard to allow pasting of images, however it fails for IE10.

For the sake of completeness:

- In chrome/webkit you have to handle event `paste` and look into  `event.clipboardData`.
- In firefox you have to create a `<div/>` with attribute `"contenteditable"`. See http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that http://snag.gy/ supports copy and paste from clipboard of images in IE 10. At least it works for me. As soon as I change the mode to IE 8/9 it only works with a Java applet.

Comment: for me it also wants to load the java applet with IE10

Comment: IE10 does not work, IE11 does: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/10/24/enhanced-rich-editing-experiences-in-ie11.aspx